# c# winforms ввод параметров подключения к базе данных через форму

Tags: c#

внутри программы существует два рабочих класса подключения к базе данных. когда IP адрес сервера меняется самом классе подключения нужно заново ввести новый IP адрес и заново компилировать программу. поэтому создал новую форму ввода параметров подключения. подключения происходит но дальше в формах возникает ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код формы ввода параметров подключения

```
    public partial class Constringg : Form
{
    public Constringg()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        private void Constringg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
    private void buttonConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format("DataSource={0}; Port={1}; Initial Catalog={2}; User ID={3}; Password={4}", hostTextbox.Text, portTextbox.Text, databaseTextbox.Text, usernameTextobx.Text, passwordTextbox.Text);
        try
        {
            SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(connectionString);
            if (helper.IsConnection)
                MessageBox.Show("connection succeeded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
        fm1.Show();
    }
}
```

класс отвечающий за подключения к базе данных

```
 class ConDatabase
{
    public static MySqlConnection GetDBConnection()
    {
          Constringg stringCon = new Constringg();
          string host = stringCon.hostTextbox.Text;
          int port = Convert.ToInt32(stringCon.portTextbox.Text);
          string database = stringCon.databaseTextbox.Text;
          string username = stringCon.usernameTextobx.Text;
          string password = stringCon.passwordTextbox.Text; 
       
        return Constring.GetDBConnection(host, port, database, username, password);
    }
}
```

класс Constring

```
class Constring
{
    public static MySqlConnection
       GetDBConnection(string host, int port, string database, string username, string password)
    {
        // Connection String.
        String connString = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database
            + ";port=" + port + ";User Id=" + username + ";password=" + password;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не ленились бы вы давать нормальные имена классам, хотя-бы перед выкладыванием кода на Stackoverflow.

Comment: странно как-то, зачем в классе Constringg открывать форму Form1 ?

Comment: @Konst, после подключения к серверу пытался перейти к основной форме, где должны отображаться данные из БД,  вот там и происходит ошибка при переходе

Comment: покажите код Constring.GetDBConnection()

Comment: @aepot,  извиняюсь это не основной код,  чтоб не ломать основной проект создаю дополнительный проект где уже изменяю, добавляю всякое

Comment: @Konst, добавил код класса Constring, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: у вас что-то не так со строкой соединения. посмотрите примеры из документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Comment: И посмотрите внимательно как вы работаете с формой в своём классе Constringg :  stringCon.hostTextbox...  Вам нужно открыть форму ввода параметров соединения с базой и в конце по кнопке взять значения из контролов и собрать строку соединения и всё. Никаких обращений к контролам формы извне не нужно.

Comment: @Konst, если прописать строку соединения внутри класса  ConDatabase, то работает, а мне хочется это сделать через форму (textbox-ов).   вот так работает `string host = "192.168.1.114";  int port = 3306;  string database = "employee", string username = "admin";  string password = "12345";`

Comment: @Konst,  а в формах что присвоит сюда  MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection(); ? тоесть другие формы должны получать строку подключения

Comment: расширьте ваш статичный класс Constring нужными параметрами соединения и заполняйте его в форме ввода

Comment: @Konst, спасибо вам за совет,  начинаю догонять ,попробую!